# Downloading js script code from a url

Tags: javascript

I have a code that loads a JS script from a URL and put it in my website.
I don't want to load the script from a URL because its depends on the URL and when the script in this URL is not working, the script in my website will not work too.
What I want to do is to download the script code and save him in the FTP as a JS file, and then to load the script from this file and not from a URL.
How do i download the script code?
Here is the code that I have right now:

```
<script src="https://spotplatform.trbinaryoptions.com/SpotOptionPlugin.js"></script>
<script>SO.load({"lang":"en","dir":"LTR","cookieOptions":{"domain":".trbinaryoptions.com"},"packages":{"Clock":{},"Balance":{},"RegularPlatform":{"settings":{"selector":"#so-trading"}}}});</script>
```

Comment: open the Js script link and press ctrl+s i.e save it. Save it by any desired name and then copy it your project folder and then include it in your project files where you have included other files like jquery and css.

Comment: Thanks first for your help!. When I press ctrl + s its save the all page. and I want only the script.

Answer (score 5):

Open the script from the browser and save the file by Pressing Ctrl + S. That is all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks first for your help!. When I press ctrl + s its save the all page, and I want only so save only the script.

Comment: You want to save this script (https://spotplatform.trbinaryoptions.com/SpotOptionPlugin.js) right?   Open this in the browser. Pressing Ctrl + S will save the page. But in this case, the whole page is js file so the browser will just save the js file.